# Is the concept of "zones of thought" specific to Vernor Vinge's work?

Tags: zones-of-thought, vernor-vinge

I'm currently reading Vernor Vinge's "A Fire upon the deep" (in French though...) and feel I'm already familiar with his idea of the deeper you are in the galaxy, the longest time you need to travel and the simplest your technology needs be... I'm nearly certain I've read something similar somewhere else, but I can't remember where. I hope someone here can connect the dots.

The *zones of thought* in Vinge's work are physical properties of space relative to galactic-sized gravity wells: the farther one is from the galactic core, the more intelligence (and super-intelligence) emerges in organisms and calculating machines, and conversely intelligent thought is physically impossible close to galactic core. Also, faster than light travel becomes possible at more remote distances from galactic center.

Comment: Never read it, but a cursory glance at your description makes me think of Piers Anthony's [Cluster books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(novels)), and the concept of 'Spherical Regression' -- basically, the farther you go out from the center of each civilization the farther they are regressed in a cultural/social way.  Our hero (for the first book) lives on Outword (named so for being on the outer fringe) and is basically a caveman, in a caveman culture, despite having more advanced education.

Comment: Seems interesting and I shall probably read it. But then that's not what I'm after.

Comment: To the user who downvoted my question: what should I have done? Provide my history of google searches? As for the usefulness, the answer below, if not what I'm seeking, may prove useful to people who want to read novels with a similar concept... I'm a newbie here, but a long time user and contributor of SO. I was told SE tried to be more welcoming... Prove it by showing what can be improved in my question.

Comment: There's an old Poul Anderson story *Brain Wave* in which the Earth has been in a "Slow Zone" for all of history and then moves out of it.  All the animals get smarter, people kind of Transcend, etc.

Comment: @odalet - I downvoted (and voted to close) because this is basically a list question. Per the FAQ ***"Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here: - Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?"***. It's also extremely vague which is the close reason I chose out of the two.

Comment: @Valorum; ok, I understand your point and get how this can lead to a list (although I'm not looking for a list) and comments and answers seem to prove you right. My question may be vague too, and I apologize for this, but I really don't see how I can make it better. i'm looking here for people with a scifi interest who could supplement my failing memory. If this is not such a place then I don't know where is. Anyway if the question is to be closed so be it, in any case I thank you for taking time to explain your vote.

Comment: @Valorum Disagree about downvote: a question of *specificity* can by falsified by a few specific examples (or even one specific example), as in the comment by Organic Marble, and the answer by Daniel Roseman.

Comment: @K-H-W [Core-Periphery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_countries) theory **is not** what the zones of thought are. The latter are physical properties of space relative to galactic-sized gravity wells, wherein the farther one is from the galactic core, the more intelligence (and super-intelligence) emerges in organisms and calculating machines, and conversely intelligent thought is physically impossible close to galactic core. Also, faster than light travel becomes possible at more remote distances from galactic center.

Comment: @Lexible - And while that's not untrue, OP is basically gonna end up with a list of works, ill-defined works at that

Comment: odalet I have taken the liberty of adding a working definition of the "zones of thought" to your question, as I feel this may improve the quality of answers you get, and may encourage some to reopen your question. Please feel free to edit, or remove if you feel this takes away from the intent of your question. Also: welcome to SFF.SE!

Comment: Short story, 1960's? Dinosaurs were initially intelligent, but became beasts when the sun's orbit around the galaxy took it into a region where neural transmissions were slower. Sir Fred Hoyle FRS comes to mind, but it doesn't really sound like him.

Comment: @Lexible -- That's why I prefaced my comment with "Never read it, but a cursory glance " -- It was a longshot based on something that sounded similar -- not really surprised it wasn't correct, but it was worth the effort of a comment, anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Alastair Reynolds has a similar concept in his book *Terminal World*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_World):

> Spearpoint and its surroundings are divided into zones: regions of space-time that exist at different energy states. Different zones support different levels of technology, and humans require periodic drug treatments to survive outside their native zone. Within Spearpoint itself, individual zones designate different precincts within the city; further away, they become much larger, with some on the opposite side of the world encompassing entire geographic regions.

Comment: I hesitated to mention it in my question, maybe I should have: I've read Terminal World and yes I remember that the lower you live on the spear the simpler the technology needs to be and it becomes worst once you leave the spear, but this is not what I have in mind, I'm more into a similar idea but at the scale of the galaxy. The very idea that if you are stuck in some zones of the galaxy you are glued there for a very long time. i'll nevertheless upvote for both concepts are indeed related! Thanks!